# How do I access and change this value via script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm not sure about how to word this but basically I'm trying to create a sort of animated glow effect for text in unity2D. To do that I need to be able to change the value of "Glow Power" through a script(shown below).

here's the value (underlined in red)
[image: here's the value (underlined in red)]

Any advice that would steer me in the right direction would be greatly Appreciated

I've been search around for a while & I can't seem to find any information on how to do it. Also, the value I'm trying to edit is attached to the component (shown below) if that makes thing's any clearer.

here's the component (underlined in red)
[image: here's the component (underlined in red)]

I tried editing it using "Get.Component" but that doesn't seem to work. Any Idea's?

Answer (score 3):

That's not a component.. it is a `Material` and what you underlined is the Shader it uses.

You will need to select the shader in the Assets in order to see which properties it exposes.

Then once you know it's name you can use e.g. [`SetFloat`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material.SetFloat.html) on the according material.

Without having Unity open a wild guess would be something like `_GlowPower` but you will need to check.

so basically

```
yourObject.GetComponent<TMP_Text>().fontMaterial.SetFloat("_GlowPower", xy);
```

Comment: Alright, I took your advice and got it working. Now I can finally build the effect I want. Thank you very much

Comment: Please make sure to accept the answer then so the question counts as resolved.